# How to download specific cardano-node binary from nixos hydra - https://hydra.iohk.io/

Tags: cardano-node

I usually go to https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/releases and follow the link to download "Hydra binaries" but I want to download version 1.35.2 because 1.35.3 is currently not working on testnet.

1. How to find version 1.35.2 on https://hydra.iohk.io/ tried with the search but without success?
2. Is there any connection between Github commits and builds on hydra?

Comment: `1.35.2` is known to have a bug. Why would you want it for any reason other than testing?

Comment: I want to test the newest version but since 1.35.3 is not working on testnet I wanted to use the newest one after that.

Answer (score 2):

In general, there is no good reason to use an older release of cardano-node. However, if you must, you can get it as follows:

- First, select the prebuilt binaries for the desired [release tag](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/tree/1.35.2) from [GitHub](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node). And look for the latest release commit or [PR for that version](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/pull/4220).
- Then scroll to the bottom of the page, look for a button that reads "View details", click it, and a list of actions will open.
- Select the **ci/hydra-eval** action and click the "details" link.
- You will be redirected to the Hydra evaluation page.
- And look for the prebuilt binaries in there. For example, if you wish to download 1.35.2 for Linux, you look for **cardano-node-1.35.2-linux**, alternatively, if you want 1.35.2 for mac look for **cardano-node-1.35.2-macos**, and click the table row to go to the build job details.
- You will see the direct download link to get a tar.gz file containing the binaries.